# super linear speedup by cache effects -- unfair comparison?

Tags: parallel-processing

It is known that super linear speedup can occur because of cache effects when using several processors as each partition of the problem fits entirely, speeding up the memory transactions over the sequential algorithm which would swap in and out several times. I've seen dozens of examples and the logic behind is very clear and well explained for the parallel part.

however, each time they compare against the sequential algorithm, the sequential algorithm is a very naive solution  with a big loop from 0...N.

Has it been considered that the sequential solution could just do the same trick as the parallel one?? (i.e partition the problem and solve each partition sequentially so that it fits in cache). In other words, just run the parallel solution in one thread. By doing this, one can expect linear speedup and not super linear as originaly thought.

What i am missing here? this counter logic seems too simple for a concept that has been out for decades.

This question came after a teacher told me "super linear speedup is impossible, you can always improve the sequential one so that there is linear speedup again". I could not prove the contrary.

Comment: You have to consider that data has to be moved from main memory into the CPU cache first (not to mention external storage IO). In the parallel case there are usually more memory controllers (either on different CPU sockets or on different system boards) and more IO ports and hence more bandwidth is available from moving data in and out. Unless you can (somehow) add more memory and IO bandwidth to the serial processor, the parallel speed-up would remain superlinear.

Comment: but having p memory controlers and p processors would just lead to linear speedup respecto to using 1 memory controller and 1 processor. By the way, i am a supporter of superlinear speedup, it is just that i am having trouble proving this to my teacher. The best i could find is Gustafson's law which accepts superlinear speedup in theory using a different approach (the fixed-time speedup model) than Amdahl's law (fixed-size speedup model).

Answer (score 1):

Superlinear speedup might come from the fact that not only the number of processors increases, but also amount of cache. The approach for the sequential case to split up the data does not increase the cache.

Comment: This is a good detail to be considered, i am analyzing it more carefully.